# Globular Cluster Particle Distribution Help

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to make a globular cluster in blender. Here's an example image of what I'm trying to make using a sphere, particles, and (if needed) geometry nodes.

[image]

At the moment, I have a geometry nodes setup that looks like this. I was unable to find a way to get particles inside the sphere. So, I filled in the sphere since it seems the particles are dependent on where the spherical mesh is. I also made the particles not be Newtonian. However, I want my sphere to be more densely packed in the center compared to the edges (like in the image above). I also want to make each of the particles glow like a star in blender (I know how to do it with standard objects via compositing and material nodes, but I don't know how I could make that work here) so that it looks like a globular cluster.

[image]

I'm now trying to add color and glow to my objects so that they act like stars in my globular cluster. However, I'm struggling to put color or a glow for the each star.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome ProximaCc, first you need a vertical edge.Then you subdivide it and you instance on each point a plane with the same subdivision (a volume cube of vertices).

[image]

You realize the instances and delete every vertices out of a sphere for this you use a `Geometry Proximity` based on the center point, and a Greater Than `Math` node the you instance your center point on the sphere.

[image]

Now you have a volume sphere. here in order to displace the point you use a `Noise Texture`, The `Vector Math` Scale control the influence of your noise, as you need something more packed in the center you can control the scale with a `Math` node Power (negative power work find) link to the `Geometry Proximity` you used before.

[image]

I hope it help.

**Edit:** My bad, in order to add a material instances should be a mesh, also you have to plug a set material at the end:

[image]

The new .blend.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! This was very helpful! I was able to get good proportions for my globular cluster so that it has an end with just a few particles on the outside. This may sound like a simple question, but how would I make the particles glow? I tried using the material panel but wasn't able to make the particles themselves glow like stars. It would also be wonderful if I could get the stars to be different colors so they can, after compositing, glow in different colors.

Comment: Those are two different questions one for the colors, you can look out this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282121/randomly-tint-generated-instances.
For the glow there is that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu3U6wD7lu4

Comment: I've tried to do both using the methods. However, when I render them, no color or glow is shown. I put a set material between the Realize Instances and Delete Geometry Nodes to add color.

Comment: I have edit the .bend and the post you should be able to do it...

Comment: I just added two more images to show you where I'm at

Comment: Try the new .blend and read the edit please.

Comment: Oh good! This is great! I was worried that the realize instances node was the node making everything not work after looking up some more videos after the ones you found. So I had the set material node in the middle of the tree

Answer (score 1):

Treating this as a geonodes project, I think this is how I would build it, taking advantage of *Mesh to Volume*.

This generates the point cloud, and it has a good bit of parametric control over density:

[image]

Make a material for the stars, spend as much time here as you want, because I think you have your work cut out for you. Different colors have different apparent brightness and it'll affect your compositing experience.  I kept it super simple.

[image]

I instanced a simple icosphere for my stars, giving them some random size

[image]

Then you render and you're into *Compositing*

In this particular example, I noticed there was a lot of green glare, and found that by modulating that channel a bit I could get some pretty good effects.

[image]

Obviously there's a lot to improve here, but that's an example of one flow.